# vuejs: Is there a way to access router.go() inside a component?

Tags: vue.js

I want to call `router.go` inside a component

currently i have set `window.router = router` // so the code works

index.js

```
const App = Vue.extend(require('./views/app.vue'))
router.start(App, '#app')
window.router = router // I don't want to set this global variable
```

navbar.vue

```
methods: {
        search () {
            window.router.go({
                name: 'search',
                query: { q: this.query }
            })
        }
}
```

what i am looking for is something like, `this.$router.go`

navbar.vue

```
methods: {
        search () {
            this.$router.go({
                name: 'search',
                query: { q: this.query }
            })
        }
    }
```

Thanks and really appreciate some help

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For `vue-router` 2.x

```
this.$router.push('path')
```

For `vue-router` 1.x

```
this.$route.router.go('path')
```

Comment: looks like in Vue2, it is now `this.$router`

Comment: I'll add that to my answer as well.